# Phrase Suggest elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I am having an issue to return a good suggestion on misspelled Ngrams.
Lets me explain in details.

Consider the following mapping with a shingle filter on 'title' field:

```
PUT _template/test_news_flo
{
"template": "test_articles_flo",
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 2,
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "filter_shingle":{ 
                "type":"shingle", 
                "max_shingle_size":5, 
                "min_shingle_size":2, 
                "output_unigrams":"true" 
            }

        },
        "analyzer": {
            "analyzer_shingle":{ 
                "tokenizer":"standard", 
                "filter":["standard", "lowercase", "filter_shingle"] 
            } 
        }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "article": {
        "_all": {  "enabled": false },
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "norms": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                    "shingle": {
                        "search_analyzer":"analyzer_shingle", 
                        "index_analyzer":"analyzer_shingle", 
                        "type":"string" 
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Add one document containing 'carla bruni' into the index test_articles_flo

```
POST /test_articles_flo/article
{
  "title": "Carla Bruni scintillante pour le Sidaction" 
}
```

Then run the following suggest phrase query:

```
 POST /test_articles_flo/_search/?size=0
 {
 "suggest": {
  "suggest-phrase-title": {
     "text": "Carla bruno",
     "phrase": {     
        "field": "title.shingle",
        "confidence": 1,
        "size": 5,
        "gram_size": 2,
        "max_errors": 2
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The following result is returned, which is exactly what I need:

```
      {
        "text": "Carla bruno",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 11,
        "options": [
           {
              "text": "carla bruni",
              "score": 0.24166171
           }
        ]
     }
```

Now add another article :

```
POST /test_articles_flo/article
{
    "title": "Le réveil de Massimo Bruno" 
}
```

Then search again with the suggest: No suggestion is given as 'bruno' is found in the index and elasticsearch considers it as valid.

Do you know how could I make the suggest return 'carla bruni' as a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work as expected when adding a direct_generator:

here is the query

```
POST /test_articles_flo/_search/?size=0
{
   "suggest": {
      "suggest-phrase-title": {
         "text": "jonnhy dep",
         "phrase": {     
            "field": "title.shingle",
            "confidence": 1,
            "size": 5,
            "gram_size": 2,
            "max_errors": 5,
            "direct_generator" : [ {
              "field" : "title.shingle",
              "suggest_mode" : "always",
              "min_word_length" : 1
            }],
            "collate": {
               "query": {
                  "match_phrase": {
                     "{{field_name}}": "{{suggestion}}"
                  }
               },
               "params": {
                  "field_name": "title.shingle"
               },
               "prune": false
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```